# For loop in R takes forever to run

Tags: r

```
    people_id  activity_id success totl_act success_rate cum_success cum_act cum_success_rate success_rate_trend
       (fctr)       (fctr)   (int)    (int)        (dbl)       (int)   (int)            (dbl)              (dbl)
1     ppl_100 act2_1734928       0        1            0           0       1                0                 NA
2     ppl_100 act2_2434093       0        1            0           0       2                0                  0
3     ppl_100 act2_3404049       0        1            0           0       3                0                  0
4     ppl_100 act2_3651215       0        1            0           0       4                0                  0
5     ppl_100 act2_4109017       0        1            0           0       5                0                  0
6     ppl_100  act2_898576       0        1            0           0       6                0                  0
7  ppl_100002 act2_1233489       1        1            1           1       1                1                  1
8  ppl_100002 act2_1623405       1        1            1           2       2                1                  0
9  ppl_100003 act2_1111598       1        1            1           1       1                1                  0
10 ppl_100003 act2_1177453       1        1            1           2       2                1                  0
```

I've this sample data frame. I want to create a variable `success_rate_trend` using `cum_success_rate` variable. The challenge is that I want it to compute for every `activity_id` except the first activity for every unique `people_id` i.e I want to capture success trend for unique `people_id`. I'm using the below code:

```
success_rate_trend<-vector(mode="numeric", length=nrow(succ_rate_df)-1)
for(i in 2:nrow(succ_rate_df)){
     if(succ_rate_df[i,1]!=succ_rate_df[i-1,1]){
         success_rate_trend[i] = NA
       }
        else {
          success_rate_trend[i]<-succ_rate_df[i,8]-succ_rate_df[i-1,8]
    }}
```

It takes forever to run. I've close to million rows in `succ_rate_df` dataframe. Can Anyone suggest how to simplify the code and reduce the run time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use vectorization:

```
success_rate_trend <- diff(succ_rate_df$cum_success_rate)
success_rate_trend[diff(as.integer(succ_rate_df$people_id)) != 0] <- NA_real_
```

Note:

1. `people_id` is a factor variable `(fctr)`. To use `diff()` we must use `as.integer()` or `unclass()` to remove the factor class.
2. You are not having an ordinary data frame, but a `tbl_df` from `dplyr`. Matrix like indexing does not work. Use `succ_rate_df$people_id` or `succ_rate_df[["people_id"]]` instead of `succ_rate_df[, 1]`.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this calculation using a vectorised approach. This will be orders of magnitude quicker.

```
n = nrow(succ_rate_df)
success_rate = succ_rate_df[2:n,1] == succ_rate_df[1:(n-1),1]
is_true = which(success_rate)

success_rate[is_true] = succ_rate_df[is_true+1,8]-succ_rate_df[is_true,8]
success_rate[!success_rate] = NA
```

---

The answer by Zheyuan Li is neater.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to offer an answer based on a dataframe version of this data. You SHOULD learn to post with the output of `dput` so that objects with special properties like the tibble you have printed above can be copied into other users consoles without loss of attributes. I'm also going to name my dataframe `dat`. The `ave` function is appropriate for calculating numeric vectors when you want them to be the same length as an input vector but want those calculations restricted to grouping vector(s). I only used one grouping factor, although you English language description of the problem suggested you wanted two. There are SO worked examples with two factors for grouping with `ave`.

```
 success_rate_trend <- with( dat, 
                    ave( cum_success_rate, people_id, FUN= function(x) c(NA, diff(x) ) ) )

 success_rate_trend
 [1] NA  0  0  0  0  0 NA  0 NA  0
 # not a very interesting result
```